# How to set up table keys with 15M+ rows for high performance and low cost?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I need to ensure best performance for a table with 15M+ rows in a MySQL database hosted in AWS using Aurora (Small sized instance currently). The table is essentially for tracking the ownership and update timestamp of product units over time, along with each unit's other basic information like serial number.

The columns are as follows:

> UnitId, ScanTime, Model, SerialNumber, MfrTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp,
> CustomerId

### Table Creation Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `UnitHistory` (
  `UnitId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ScanTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Model` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `SerialNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MfrTimestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UpdateTimestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UnitId`,`ScanTime`)
);
```

Rows will be added over time, but NEVER modified.

I chose UnitId and ScanTime as the primary key because those two together are sufficient to always be unique.

### Query 1

The query I'll most frequently use will ideally produce a list of all UnitId's for a specific Model, along with the unit's most up-to-date details.
The following query will work, but will of course also return more rows than I need (redundant data):

```
SELECT UnitId, SerialNumber, MfrTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp, CustomerId FROM UnitHistory WHERE Model=2500;
```

If there's a way to constrain that query so that only the row with the most recent ScanTime is returned for any given UnitId, that would be ideal.
Otherwise I'll simply search the result for the row with the most recent ScanTime for each UnitId afterward.

### Query 2

The other very frequently used query will produce a basic set of details and history for any particular unit, like this:

```
SELECT ScanTime, SerialNumber, MfrTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp, CustomerId FROM UnitHistory WHERE UnitId=1234567;
```

This query will primarily be used to track the change of ownership as it passes from the manufacturer to a customer, then
back to the manufacturer for update, then out to perhaps a different customer, etc.

### Summary

With the above scenario, what additional key(s) should I have in order to ensure good performance and low cost?

One cost factor is that I assume my working set should fit within RAM in order to avoid lots of IOs since AWS charges for IOs.
My current database instance has 2 GB RAM, and for cost reasons I don't want to upgrade it.

Comment: you can't have  top performance without spending some $$. Can you post your execution resuts for query1 and 2?

Comment: @krishKM I probably should have stated "top performance using 2GB RAM". I haven't actually populated the table with data and run queries against it yet because the software that populates it isn't ready yet. I'm just trying to have the table prepared and functioning the best it can for when the data is finally populated.

Comment: so this becomes a non-existent & opinion based question! you can look up for partitions and table triggers and improve your table design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query 1, you should have this index:

```
ALTER TABLE UnitHistory ADD INDEX (Model, ScanTime);
```

To get the most recent:

```
SELECT UnitId, SerialNumber, MfrTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp, CustomerId 
FROM UnitHistory WHERE Model=2500
ORDER BY ScanTime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Here's a demo of using EXPLAIN to confirm the query uses the index (which is named "Model" after the first column of the index since I didn't give it a name in my test):

```
mysql> explain SELECT UnitId, SerialNumber, MfrTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp, CustomerId FROM UnitHistory WHERE Model=2500 order by scantime desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | UnitHistory | NULL       | ref  | Model         | Model | 8       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Your other query 1 is already searching by the left-most column of the primary key, so there's no need to add another index.

```
mysql> explain SELECT ScanTime, SerialNumber, MfrTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp, CustomerId FROM UnitHistory WHERE UnitId=1234567;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | UnitHistory | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

I can't predict whether your working set will fit in RAM, because I don't know the distribution of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an audit table and you are taking readings for units?
Partitioning tables, having views or prepared statements are some possible ways.

Here another way for **Query1**. Create another table like your UnitHistory. `Create table UnitReadings like UnitHistory; but unitid being the primary key`.

And then alter you `UnitHistory` table and add triggers before insert or after insert. something like,

```
 Insert into `UnitReading`(
    UnitId,
    ScanTime,
    Model,
    SerialNumber,
    MfrTimestamp,
    UpdateTimestamp,
    CustomerId
  ) values
  (
      NEW.UnitId,
      NEW.ScanTime,
      NEW.Model,
      NEW.SerialNumber,
      NEW.MfrTimestamp,
      NEW.UpdateTimestamp,
      NEW.CustomerId
  ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      ScanTime          = values(ScanTime),
      Model             = values(Model), 
      SerialNumber      = values(SerialNumber),
      MfrTimestamp      = values(MfrTimestamp),
      UpdateTimestamp   = values(UpdateTimestamp),
      CustomerId        = values(CustomerId);
```

The goal ist to keep the latest reading in a **"header table"** which might have less rows than your entire history of your (readings * per day * days) rows. After few years you might exceed 15m rows but your header table could still be around 1000 units or whatever amount of units you are taking readings of. You may well exceed your performance expectation usign this header table "withing your 2GB RAM" :) :)

Not sure if you can implement this but you get the idea right?